# Format size different on some Multiline text when I print to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, caml-query, multiline-text-field

I created my own custom print page (HTML) from a SharePoint List.  The only issue is, some of the multi-line text is showing up in different font-sizes when printing to PDF or Print Preview in IE or Chrome.  I tried, inline, external, !important, and nothing seem to work.  Is there way to make the font-size uniformed?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the solution.  In the CSS Media Print element, we used the incorrect tag element.  Instead of td, we used th.  Once we changed it, the print showed the correct font-family and size.

Comment: Hi, adams-j. Thanks for your enthusiastic sharing, you can mark your answer. Convenient for other users who faced this problem to reference. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably that your create a Multi-lines text column with **Enhanced rich text**.

[image]

`Note`:**This type of multi-line text field can customize the font style.**

[image]

Therefore, I suggest you can create a Multi-lines text column with **Plain text**.

[image]
[image]